# How to partially blur an image in the compositor?

Tags: compositing-nodes

I want to blur an image I used as a background in the compositor but have it blurred more towards the top and in focus in the foreground.  Is this possible to do with nodes?

Thanks

[image]

This is the node setup:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a new Texture in the Texture properties panel set to Blend and Vertical. This will create a texture that blends from 1.0 at the top to 0 at the bottom.

In the compositor the texture can be included via the Texture node. This can then be passed into the Blur node set to Variable Size as follows :

[image: nodes and result]

Note the result in the bottom-left window (blur at the top, sharper towards the bottom). You can use Maths nodes or a Color Ramp between the Texture and the Blur node to adjust if desired.

Answer (score 3):

you can use the box mask node. if you need a gradient from top to bottom you could blur the box mask

[image]

[image]

Comment: Totally worked!